# Why isn't a warning required to obligate a fine?

Tags: money, beit-din-court, knas-penalty, hasraah-warning

The Torah says that by capital punishment ([Hilchos Issurei Bi'ah 1:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.1.2?lang=bi&with=Maggid%20Mishneh&lang2=en)) and by lashes ([Hilchos Sanhedrin 16:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_The_Sanhedrin_and_the_Penalties_within_their_Jurisdiction.16.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) a person  must be given proper *hasra'ah* (warning) before a punishment can be administered.

However, when it comes to fines- for example a rapist or seducer- such a warning is **NOT** required. For example, Rambam in [Na'arah Besulah 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Virgin_Maiden.1.8?lang=bi) writes:

> אֵין הָאוֹנֵס אוֹ הַמְפַתֶּה חַיָּב בִּקְנָס עַד שֶׁיָּבוֹא עָלֶיהָ [כְּדַרְכָּהּ] וּבְעֵדִים **וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ הַתְרָאָה**.‏
>
> The rapist or seducer isn't obligated to pay the fine until he has relations with her [in the ordinary fashion], and with witnesses present, **and a warning is not necessary**.

Why is a warning required to administer capital punishment and lashes, but isn't required to obligate a fine?

Comment: Just a guess here:  the warning was required because they wanted to avoid capital punishment and severe beatings as much as possible(every 7 years, or even less often, and the Bet Din is called "destructive"is in Talmud somewhere), whereas there was no such stigma attached to collecting fines. Then, as today, it was a good way for the municipality or state to amass funds.

Comment: Perhaps a fine is considered less severe than capital punishment? Just throwing the idea out there

Comment: Wait, do you ask specifically about אונס ומפתה or only in נפשות or just about any fine? Like in damages?

Comment: From Rambam you quote it seems that the ruling is specifically limited to אונס ומפתה>

Comment: @AlBerko any fine- just there aren't many explicit fines listed in the Torah (4 to my knowledge)

Comment: So why do you think then that Rambam generalized to all fines? He says only אונס ומפתה.

Comment: @AlBerko the Rambam does mention a warning for *motzei shem ra* https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Virgin_Maiden.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en yet seems to not explicitly mention a warning for *eved c'naani* https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Slaves.3.14?lang=bi

Comment: How would you warn a Ganav?

Comment: @Gary these fines don't go to the municipality or state.  They go to the person who was harmed.

Comment: @DoubleAA right, would be very unlikely- paying כפל or ד׳ וה׳ would also be a fine. For אונס מפתה would be much more capable of warning

Comment: @Heshy-You're absolutely right, sorry for the misguess. I had passed through a trap where they were literally hiding behind a tree and then signaling his coworker who was waiting to pull them over and give out seat belt/phone/etc tickets on the way home. Definitely not like Torah fines, more like Roman informer stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The Torah requires for *misas Beis din* (death penalty) we have to be 100% sure that the perpetrator knew what he was doing and that he didn't forget the warning/didn't know what he was doing was bad, hence one needs warning תוך כדי דיבור (within the time of a greeting to ones teacher) to warn the guy prior to his sin, see [Kesubos 33a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.33a.5-6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Otherwise they'd kill someone who might have forgotten the warning and not realized what he did was wrong so even 99% is not good enough rather warn him just before he sins then we know its on purpose.

The reason why we have to be so sure is learned from Kesubos 15a ([explained by Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.15a.14?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Ketubot.15a.14.2&lang2=bi)):

> **ספק נפשות** - דיני נפשות להקל דהא והצילו העדה כתיב- במדבר לה
>
> death sentences are judged favorably towards the offender since it is written in Bamidbar 35:"The Congregation (sanhedrin) shall save" .

Note that Malkus (lashes) with regards to forewarning is the same as death sentence either because it weakens the person like death

> מה לי קטלה כולה מה לי קטלה פלגא
> [Bava Kamma 65a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.65a.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

or there is a Hekesh between Malkus and Misa
(source: Tosfos Yeshanim Kesubos 36b)

However in k'nas offenses there is no such *gezeiras Hakasuv* that "the congregation should save the perpetrator" and require warning, therefore the Torah dictates without reason that in all the cases of Knas- *Oneis, Mefateh, Motzi shem ra, Shor shenagach Eved, Keifel, Arba vechamesh*- one simply pays without warning.

After all, one cannot warn an ox to not gore a slave and the owner would be liable despite his utmost care to prevent the killing e.g the ox runs away, and even if the slave is worth absolutely nothing the owner of the ox is still liable to pay a knas of 30 silver coins (see [Gittin 43a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.43a.3-7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)).